# Processes running even after logged out and logged in as another user

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu

I noticed this as there is `xiccd` running even if I have disabled it for current user (because of [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xiccd/+bug/1845800)).

Why is this? How do you prevent this? If this is a bug, against which package the report should be made?

Here is extraction of `ps aux` concerning another user:

```
tv        9836  0.0  0.2  77120  8356 ?        Ss   09:50   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
tv        9837  0.0  0.0 195844  2584 ?        S    09:50   0:00 (sd-pam)
tv        9868  0.0  0.1  50492  5020 ?        Ss   09:50   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
tv        9960  0.0  0.1 349188  6072 ?        Ssl  09:50   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher
tv        9965  0.0  0.1  50064  4140 ?        S    09:50   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
tv        9970  0.0  0.1 263924  5692 ?        Sl   09:50   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/xfconf/xfconfd
tv        9986  0.0  0.1 293652  7312 ?        Ssl  09:50   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
tv        9991  0.0  0.1 416112  5408 ?        Sl   09:50   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1001/gvfs -f -o big_writes
tv       10036  0.0  0.8 263256 32808 ?        Sl   09:50   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/system-config-printer/applet.py
tv       10042 98.5  0.2 911744  8256 ?        Rl   09:50  40:27 xiccd
tv       10060  0.0  0.2 307996  8316 ?        Ssl  09:50   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
tv       10069  0.0  0.1 290476  6808 ?        Ssl  09:50   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
tv       10074  0.0  0.1 380504  7836 ?        Ssl  09:50   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
tv       10083  0.0  0.1 277556  5096 ?        Ssl  09:50   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
tv       10091  0.0  0.1 275724  6084 ?        Ssl  09:50   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
tv       10102  0.0  0.1 187904  5240 ?        Sl   09:50   0:00 /usr/lib/dconf/dconf-service
tv       10139  0.0  0.1  81612  5928 ?        S    09:50   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconf/gconfd-2
tv       10142  0.0  0.1 369664  7144 ?        Sl   09:50   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.12 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0
tv       10152  0.0  0.1 206052  4944 ?        Ssl  09:50   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-metadata
tv       10186  0.0  0.1  82728  6932 ?        Ss   09:50   0:00 /usr/lib/bluetooth/obexd
```